# I want to update user profile picture in all the posts as well he posted when user updated/Change his profile picture

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akyjd.png)[image]
I am updating user profile picture and it works perfectly in all activities i want. But problem is that it does not update user profile picture in all the posts user already posted. I want to update user's profile picture there as well.

This is database Reference

```
postRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");
```

Here is my Recycler view setup

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Posts> options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>()
            .setQuery(postRef,Posts.class)
            .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts,PostsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder>(options)
    {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Posts model) {

            final String postKey=getRef(position).getKey();

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent clickPostIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, ClickPostActivity.class);
                    clickPostIntent.putExtra("postKey",postKey);
                    startActivity(clickPostIntent);
                }
            });

            holder.username.setText(model.getFullname());
            holder.date.setText(model.getDate());
            holder.time.setText(model.getTime());

            if (model.getPost_uri_link()!=null){
                holder.post_link.setText(model.getPost_uri_link());
            }
            else {
                holder.post_link.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (model.getPost_file_name()!=null && model.getPost_file_uri()!=null) {
                holder.file_attach_name.setText(model.getPost_file_name());
                holder.file_attach_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        downloadFile(MainActivity.this,model.getPost_file_name(),"gs://studentcornerproject-be4c6.appspot.com/post files",model.getPost_file_uri());
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                holder.file_attach_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (model.getDescription()!=null) {
                holder.description.setText(model.getDescription());
           }
            else {
                holder.description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (model.getPost_img()!=null) {
                Picasso.get().load(model.post_img).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).placeholder(android.R.drawable.progress_indeterminate_horizontal).into(holder.post_img, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                        postRef.child("post_img").keepSynced(true);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {

                        Picasso.get().load(model.post_img).into(holder.post_img);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                holder.post_img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            Picasso.get().load(model.getProfile_image()).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_icon).into(holder.prof_img, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {

                    Picasso.get().load(model.getProfile_image()).into(holder.prof_img);
                }
            });
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public PostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

            View view= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_posts_users,viewGroup,false);
            PostsViewHolder viewHolder=new PostsViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;

        }
    };
    postslist.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}

public static class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

   TextView username,date,time,description,file_attach_name,post_link;
    CircleImageView prof_img;
    ImageView post_img;

    public PostsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        post_link=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_link);
        username=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_user_name);
        date=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_date);
        time=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_time);
        description=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_description);
        file_attach_name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_filename);
        prof_img=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_profile_img);
        post_img=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);


    }
```

I want to update profile picture in all the posts he already posted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been solved. here is the correct code.

```
 Query postQuery=postRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(currentUserId);
        postQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Log.i("Post",snapshot.getKey());
                    postRef.child(snapshot.getKey()).child("profile_image").setValue(profile_img);
                    postRef.child(snapshot.getKey()).child("fullname").setValue(fullname);




                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your userID node you should store the ids of the post of that user, with that you can then just change the photo_url of all the posts the user has made.

Example

```
Users
|______UserID
       |_ userPosts
         |_ postID
```

Then, when you change the photo_url of the user, you can retrieve all the posts and change the same photo_url

Comment: I am already storing user id in each post he made. I am retrieving all the posts. But problem is updating picture in old posts.

Comment: no, you are storing inside the userID the data of the user, but not the data of the post, you should have the post id inside your userid data inside Users

Comment: I have attached my another picture of my posts node. Please check it above. There is uid already stored to link post to that user who posted